# clear all activities in Login activity

Tags: android

My application looks like this,
Login -> screen1 -> screen2 -> screen3 -> screen4.
If the user is not active in 30 sec, the login screen will appear. If the user enters correct password the last screen should appear again, if he presses back button the application should finish.
I also go through some answers in stackoverflow,but I didn't solve the problem.

Comment: use `finish();`

Comment: If user enters the correct password then launch the intent to open last screen and inside last activity override this method `onBackPressed()` and call finish(); inside it.

Answer (score 0):

1) If the user is not active in 30 sec, the login screen will appear

You can call startActivity(new Intent(this,Login.class));

2) If the user enters correct password the last screen should appear again

call finish();

3) if he presses back button the application should finish.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        exit(0);
    }
```

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the **timertask** to run in background and when the 30 second finished you can set logout after it.

```
private Timer mTimer1;
private TimerTask mTt1;
private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();

private void stopTimer(){
    if(mTimer1 != null){
        mTimer1.cancel();
        mTimer1.purge();
    }
}

private void startTimer(){
    mTimer1 = new Timer();
    mTt1 = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mTimerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    //TODO
                }
            });
        }
    };

    mTimer1.schedule(mTt1, 1, 5000);//for 5 second
}
```

You can set it log out after the time is over.

if user click any where you need to enable/restart the timer and keep the tracking of screens

when user login you can take the screen and navigate to it over there.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you need to use noHistory for Login Activity in the Manifest it would appear only through intent not via back button.

For screen Activity use

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

so once user press back button in screen Activity App will close.. or else you navigate to Particular screen Activity with the help of intent..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,TargetActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```